# Handles equivilent in c# for Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have the following ASP control:

```
<div class="pageNumSec">
    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnPrevious" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click" CssClass="directForBackBtn" Text="<< Previous Page"></asp:LinkButton>

    <asp:repeater runat="server" ID="rptPager">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnPageNumber" CssClass="pageNum" Text='<%#Container.DataItem%>' CommandArgument='<%#Container.DataItem%>'></asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:repeater>

    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnNext" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click"  CssClass="directForBackBtn" Text="Next Page >>"></asp:LinkButton>
</div>
```

This displays page numbers as links.

This is the code that is meant to be a) making these links update the page & b) highlighting the current page in bold:

```
//navigate by using the page number links
protected void rptPager_ItemCommand(object source, System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    _pageNumber = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    PopulatePage(_pageNumber);
}

//make the current page bold
protected void rptPager_ItemDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    //is current item the current page.
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        int currentPage = Convert.ToInt32(e.Item.DataItem);
        LinkButton currentLinkBtn = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("btnPageNumber");

        //if true, highlight text
        if (currentPage == _pageNumber || (currentPage == 1 && _pageNumber == 0))
        {
            currentLinkBtn.Font.Bold = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Currently, neither of these methods are firing when you interact with the page, these methods have been re-written in C# from VB.Net. The only difference I can see in the original code is that the VB contained `Handles` keywords like so:

```
Protected Sub rptPager_ItemCommand(source As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterCommandEventArgs) Handles rptPager.ItemCommand

    _pageNumber = Integer.Parse(e.CommandArgument)

    PopulatePage(_pageNumber)

End Sub



Protected Sub rptPager_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rptPager.ItemDataBound
    'is current item the current page.

    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem OrElse
        e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Then

        Dim currentPage As Integer = CType(e.Item.DataItem, Integer)
        Dim currentLinkBtn As LinkButton = CType(e.Item.FindControl("btnPageNumber"), LinkButton)

        'if true, highlight text
        If currentPage = _pageNumber OrElse (currentPage = 1 AndAlso _pageNumber = 0) Then
            currentLinkBtn.Font.Bold = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Can anyone advise me how to wire these methods up to the ASP so that the links work and the current page number is bold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the handlers to your Repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptPager"
    OnItemDataBound="rptPager_ItemDataBound"
    OnItemCommand="rptPager_ItemCommand">
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was missing!